# VBA - can I get a list of filter options available in a table programmatically?

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I'm trying to copy and paste a series of table data onto a new sheet where the data is filtered by "Yes" and then "No."

Some tables do not have any "No"s, some do not have "Yes", and others have both.

Is there a way to check if the filter exists before trying to filter the table in VBA?

Thanks!

Comment: `Application.Match` or `Application.CountIfs`, which are just the late-bound versions of `WorksheetFunction.Match` and `WorksheetFunction.CountIfs`, maybe.

Comment: thanks - with my use case an "If Not ISError(Application.Match("etcetcetc))" worked out well!